# Assign primitive max and min

Tags: java, binary, max, min, primitive-types

To remember the maximum and minimum values for each integer primitive in decimal is quite difficult.  Not so difficult for binary and hex.  I understand that the wrapper classes have these values built in, but I like working with binary and hex.  The problem is that I try

// value is byte
value = 0x80; // 1000_0000

but it doesn't work.  But (after a little research),

value = -0x80;

and

value = (byte) 0x80;

both work.  I thought that when assigning a literal to the smaller integer primitives, no cast is necessary.  Are the binary, octal, and hex values considered literals or are they all 32 bits because they are not decimal?  Any help in understanding what is going on is welcome.

Comment: As long as the literal fits into the primitive type, it works fine, but `0x80` does not fit in a `byte`, as `byte` is signed.  The largest possible byte is `0x7f`.

Comment: You're not specifying the bit pattern `10000000` with that `0x80` literal; you're specifying the value 128.

Comment: I was thinking that since a cast is not needed for literal decimal numbers assigned to byte,short, and char, a cast wouldn't be needed for binary or hexadecimal. To me, it seemed that 0x80 would be no different than -128 because as a byte they both have the same bit pattern and they were both being assigned to the same signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

To remember the maximum and minimum values, use the built in constants:

```
int iMax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
byte bMin = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
```

Binary, octal, and hex values are evaluated in compile time as if their decimal equivalent were written. Some examples:

```
byte b1 = 0b1111111; //OK (same as byte b1 = 127)
byte b2 = 0b10000000; //possible lossy conversion (compiler does not know if you tried to insert the byte -128 or the int 128)

int i1 = 0xFFFFFFFF; //OK
int i2 = 0xFFFFFFFFF; //too large to fit inside int
```